# Setting size for custom UI in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am building a custom IBDesignable UIView called MyUIView that will be instantiated from an .xib file. MyUIView is meant to be reused across my app.

The problem i faced is that when i create a MyUIView view in a UIViewController in a storyboard, autolayout requires me to provide constraints for the view's width and height. MyUIView has variable height and i was hoping that the view can just wrap the width and height of the rendered MyUIView without me specifying the size of the view in storyboard.

How do i achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Override [`intrinsicContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/intrinsicContentSize) in your view class. The autolayout engine will use this size for your view unless you specify otherwise with explicit constraints.

Note that you will have to call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` on your view whenever its intrinsic size should change.

Comment: i have done that but autolayout still requires me to provide a height   `override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 85)
  }`

Comment: Btw, the docs say "Returns the natural size for the receiving view, **considering only properties of the view itself**", so I'm not sure using the screen width is valid.

Comment: Yes. For this particular view, it needs to be always filling the screen width